# Moodlle package: problem with includegraphics and tikzpicture

Tags: moodle

For me, there are still two problems in the XML file as a result of moodle package, when includegraphics command and tikzpicture environment are used. Both of them cannot appear on the moodle site. How to handle it?

I have obtained some clues, as stated in the following document.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fouriernc,sourceserifpro}
\usepackage[draft]{moodle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\def\graphicspath#1{\def\Ginput@path{#1}\edef\moodleimgpath{\@firstofone#1}}

\xpatchcmd{\moodle@includegraphics@int@int}%
{\openssl\otherspace enc -base64 -in #2.jpg -out #2.enc}%
{\openssl\otherspace enc -base64 -in \moodleimgpath#2.jpg -out #2.enc}%
{\typeout{patch ok}}%
{\typeout{patch failed}}
\makeatother

\graphicspath{{./gambar/}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newsavebox\picbox
\begin{lrbox}{\picbox}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \draw[thick] (0,0) circle(1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{lrbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{quiz}{Pelatihan 1}
  \begin{multi}[shuffle=true, points=1]{{\em Corona Virus Disease}-19}
    Soal ini berbentuk pilihan berganda.

    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{covid-19}

  \item* 1
  \item 2
\end{multi}

\begin{numerical}[points=2]{Tentang soal nomor 2}
Soal ini berbentuk numerik dan opsinya berupa {\em itemize}.
\item 11
\end{numerical}

\begin{shortanswer}[case sensitive=true]{Tentang soal nomor 3}
Soal ini berbentuk {\em case sensitive} dan opsinya berupa {\em itemize}.
\item Benar
\item[fraction=0, feedback={Bukan, Bro!}] Salah
\item{fraction=50} Bukan jawaban
\end{shortanswer}

\begin{multi}[points=3]{Turunan pertama}
Apa turunan pertama dari $x^3$?
\item $\frac{1}{4} x^4+C$
\item* $3x^2$
\end{multi}

\begin{multi}{Gambar}
Apakah ini sebuah lingkaran?

\usebox\picbox

      \item* Ya
      \item Bukan
    \end{multi}
\end{quiz}

\end{document}
```

I got the image from [here](https://pripos.id/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/Coronavirus-Research.jpg).

Comment: Please provide a MWE that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Never worked with `tikz` for me, but `includegraphics` works correctly. Are you running with `-shell-escape`? Then, you can't really use most of macros with `moodle.sty`, and you are using deprecated commands (like `\em`).

Comment: @Rmano, Yes, I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well --- this is from my experience **(please notice that I do not understand the language in which the test is written, at all. So I do not take responsibility about it)** (better use English next time, please!):

1. `moodle.sty` patches things in `tikz`, and I really never managed to make it work. So I normally use an external, standalone file to generate the image and then include it with `includegraphics`.
2. Also, graphic paths are tricky --- although there is a patch floating around, I prefer to simply add the image in the same directory and forget it.
3. You are patching `graphicx` (I do not know why), and using `\em` which is deprecated since at least 30 years... ;-) --- it has to use `\emph{text}` which is the correct way.
4. The patch you are applying to the moodle include command is failing: in the log you have:

   ```
   ...
   patch failed
   (./testm.aux)
   *geometry* driver: auto-detecting
   ...
   ```

So, this code here:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[]{moodle}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{quiz}{Pelatihan 1}
  % You can't use commands in the test name!
  \begin{multi}[shuffle=true, points=1]{Corona Virus Disease-19}
    Soal ini berbentuk pilihan berganda.

    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{covid-19.jpg}

  \item* 1
  \item 2
\end{multi}

\begin{numerical}[points=2]{Tentang soal nomor 2}

Soal ini berbentuk numerik dan opsinya berupa \emph{itemize}.
\item 11
\end{numerical}

\begin{shortanswer}[case sensitive=true]{Tentang soal nomor 3}
Soal ini berbentuk \emph{case sensitive} dan opsinya berupa \emph{itemize}.
\item Benar
\item[fraction=0, feedback={Bukan, Bro!}] Salah
\item{fraction=50} Bukan jawaban
\end{shortanswer}

\begin{multi}[points=3]{Turunan pertama}
Apa turunan pertama dari $x^3$?
\item $\frac{1}{4} x^4+C$
\item* $3x^2$
\end{multi}

\begin{multi}{Gambar}
Apakah ini sebuah lingkaran?

      \item* Ya
      \item Bukan
    \end{multi}
\end{quiz}

\end{document}
```

works correctly if the file `covid-19.jpg` is in the same directory and compiled with `pdflatex -shell-escape testm.sty`.

[image]

...and the first one:

[image]

If you have problems in the inclusion of the image, check that the conversion is working ok in the log file (or in the output); in my case it is:

```
...
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
moodle.sty: Processing \includegraphics[width=6cm]{covid-19.jpg} for HTML...
moodle.sty: Converting 'covid-19.jpg' to PNG...
moodle.sty: Converting 'covid-19.jpg.png' to base64...
moodle.sty: Reading base64 file 'covid-19.jpg.enc'...
moodle.sty: <IMG> tag inserted.
...
```

To help debug graphical problems, you can [download this file as `moodleshow.tex`](https://gist.github.com/Rmano/10c932098553702b722f3a8e0f67a104) and then add

```latex
\input{moodleshow.tex}
```

in your preamble (after loading `moodle` package), it will print additional info in the log file like this:

```
moodle.sty: Processing \includegraphics[width=6cm]{covid-19.jpg} for HTML...
moodle.sty: Converting 'covid-19.jpg' to PNG...
command is: convert covid-19.jpg -resize 472 covid-19.jpg.png
command is: openssl enc -base64 -in covid-19.jpg.png -out covid-19.jpg.enc
command is: openssl enc -base64 -in covid-19.jpg.png -out covid-19.jpg.enc
moodle.sty: Reading base64 file 'covid-19.jpg.enc'...
moodle.sty: <IMG> tag inserted.
```

About the circle image, you can generate a PDF using `tikz` and the `standalone` class, and then include it with `\includegrahics{}` as well.

Comment: What about the circle (=lingkaran) picture on the last question? Do (as you mentioned) using \includegraphics command?

Comment: I use your code, but \includegraphics still do not work.

Comment: Please add the log of the relevant error; also tell the version of your TeX system. I can't help if I don't know the error you have...

Comment: I mean, the XML file can't display images on the moodle site. While compilation and the results (PDF) are going well.

Comment: @kalakay I added lot of things and tried the inclusion. I also shown my log stating the correct conversion of the image, your problem is probably there.

Comment: Right, moodle package converts PDF image files into PNGs like that. But when the XML file was uploaded to the moodle site, the images did not appear. I was forced to edit them one by one by uploading the PNG files.Could the images (PNG) in the XML file appear automatically on the moodle site?

Comment: For me it appears automatically. It is the conversion from `png` to `base64` that does the trick. If that fails you will have the effect you say here... you can check it manually.

Comment: FYI, I use Windows 10, TeX Live 2020, and TeXworks.

Comment: Hmmm.... do you have `openssl` installed and in your PATH? I mean, opening a terminal and typing `openssl` show give something, not a "command not found" error. (I edited a bit the answer to help you debug the problem; unfortunately I know nothing of Windows... Unix only here).

Comment: No, I have no openssl.

Comment: So that's the problem. Without a tool to convert the `png` to `base64` you will have no automatic inclusion. Please refer to chapter 5 of the manual...

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot. Any solution about openssl for Windows?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625283/how-to-install-openssl-in-windows-10 ?

Comment: Windows 10 should embed a base64 utility with CertUtils. I don't have windows to test this but you could try to add this in your preamble `\opensslcommand{certutil}` and `\makeatletter\xpatchcmd{\moodle@includegraphics@int@int}{enc -base64 -in #2.png -out #2.enc}{-encode #2.png tmp.b64 && findstr /vbc:"---" tmp.b64 > #2.enc && del tmp.b64"}{\typeout{patch ok}}{\typeout{patch failed}}\makeatother`