# moodle.sty won't incorporate base64 code

Tags: graphics, xml, moodle

This question is very similar to that found here: [moodle.sty does not insert graphics in xml output file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/539721/moodle-sty-does-not-insert-graphics-in-xml-output-file) (though as I'm a new user I can't comment on the original question).  I'm using Windows, MiKTeX (edit: this was wrong, it's actually TeX Live 2018) and Texmaker, and I'd like to build quizzes efficiently in Moodle for a precalculus course.  I'm quite new with LaTeX, only having worked with it for a year.

I'm currently trying to use a .png graphic located in the same directory as the .tex file. When I run PDFLaTeX, I get the following warning "Package ifplatform Warning:shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows"

[image: Warning Output "Package ifplatform Warning:shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows"]

This was after adjusting the Configuration of PDFLaTeX to include --shell-escape=true as Gustavo did in the original post:

[image: Configuration of PDFLaTeX to include --shell-escape=true]

For reference, here is the section of the log that I think is showing how moodle.sty is managing the graphic:

```
<map1.pdf, id=1, 361.35pt x 216.81pt>
File: map1.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use map1.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: map1.pdf  used on input line 29.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 170.71652pt x 102.43002pt.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 29.

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 29.

(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
)
moodle.sty: Processing \includegraphics[width=6cm]{map1.pdf} for HTML...
moodle.sty: Converting 'map1.pdf' to PNG...
command is: convert map1.pdf -resize 243 map1.pdf.png
runsystem(convert map1.pdf -resize 243 map1.pdf.png)...executed.

command is: openssl enc -base64 -in map1.pdf.png -out map1.pdf.enc
runsystem(openssl enc -base64 -in map1.pdf.png -out map1.pdf.enc)...executed.

command is: openssl enc -base64 -in map1.pdf.png -out map1.pdf.enc
moodle.sty: Reading base64 file 'map1.pdf.enc'...
moodle.sty: <IMG> tag inserted.
[1

{c:/texlive/2018/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} <./map1.pdf>]
(./circles.aux) )
```

Finally, here is the section of the .xml where the decoded base64 image should be:

```
  <questiontext format="html">
    <text><![CDATA[<p>Which equation describes the following map: <BR/> <IMG width=243 SRC="data:image/png;base64,"> </p>]]></text>
  </questiontext>
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

The only other thing I can notice in the log is:

```
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/shellesc.sty
Package: shellesc 2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 69.
```

Thanks for your time,

Fraser

PS If I manually convert the .png to base64 and insert it into the .xml file I can get it to upload into Moodle, but I'd like to make large banks of questions efficiently using gnuplot, LaTeX, and Moodle

---

Thanks @Ulrike Fischer, here's the full .tex file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{moodle}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\input{moodleshow.tex}

\begin{document}

\begin{quiz}{Point form Circles}
  \begin{multi}[shuffle=true]{Circle Equation}
    Which equation describes the following map: \\
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{map1.pdf}   
    \item* $(x + 1)^2 + (y-3)^2 = 4$
    \item $(x-1)^2 + (y + 3)^2 = 4$
    \item $(x-1)^2 + (y-3)^2 = 4$
    \item $(x + 1)^2 + (y + 3)^2 = 4$
  \end{multi}
\end{quiz}

\end{document}
```

---

Note for @Rmano, here's the result of encrypting the .png after converting manually with ImageMagick:

[image: Success manually encrypting with correct base64 code in the background]

---

Update: Transient Message

Well this is weird... the error "'openssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." only shows up while pdfLaTeX is running (I had to hit "PrntScrn" at just the right time to get it; afterwards it simply shows "No LaTeX errors detected!")

[image: 'openssl' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.]

---

Update: magick convert through openssl cmd prompt.

Thanks again to both of you.  Here's what I get when I run `pdflatex -shell-escape circles.tex` through the OpenSSL Command Prompt, versus what the last bit of the log is saying:

[image: OpenSSL cmd output versus the .log file]

---

Resolved: Thanks to @UlrikeFischer and @Rmano for resolving the issue!  Including `\imagemagickcommand{magick convert}` and running the .tex file through openSSL via `pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex' and everything turns out as it should.

Comment: you should show a small complete example, so that one can test your issue.

Comment: well I don't have the moodleshow.tex file and the convert command is called `magick convert` on my system. If I add `\imagemagickcommand{magick convert}` to the file I get a png with `--shell-escape`. I don't have openssl so the next step fails.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The `moodleshow.tex` hack (really hack, */blush*) is mine and it's here: https://gist.github.com/Rmano/10c932098553702b722f3a8e0f67a104

Comment: @UlrikeFischer and fcturner: I checked your code on my system and it works ok. All the intermediary files (called `mod1.pdf.png` and `mod1.pdf.enc`) are created in the same directory. So it must be some windows peculiarity of both `convert` and `openssl` --- and I'm really at a loss here. Try to go to the directory where the `.tex` here, isuue `pdflatex -shell-escape myfile.tex` and see if you have errors or a blank `.enc` file. (I have to shut down now, will try to help more tomorrow)

Comment: The `- resize` error also is strange. Probably @UlrikeFischer comment above is relevant, `pdflatex` is running the wrong `convert`. The other can be a PATH problem...

Comment: Hey @UlrikeFischer and @Rmano - you were right.  It was in the convert command, that should be "magick convert" instead... see the log above versus the openssl cmd output.  After doing it manually, the `map1.pdf.png` and `map1.pdf.enc` files are both there.  So, should I be patching the moodle package with "magick convert" instead of "convert"?

Comment: There is not need to patch the package. The package allows to change the command name, simply add the `\imagemagickcommand{magick convert}` I mentioned to your document.

Comment: Hi @UlrikeFischer, I forgot to mention that I tried your suggestion first within Tekmaker, but it didn't change the output.  Doing everything in openssl cmd prompt (with magick convert instead of just convert) DID work though....

Comment: Okay, so including @UlrikeFischer 's change of command AND using an OpenSSL cmd window to run `pdflatex -shell-escape circles.tex` made it run just fine.  It must be something with how I have TeXMaker configured.  Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert of MikTeX (and the logs you have are from TeXLive, and not miktex), but:

```
Package ifplatform Warning:shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows
```

```
moodle.sty: Processing \includegraphics[width=6cm]{map1} for HTML...
moodle.sty: Converting 'map1' to PNG...
runsystem(convert map1 -resize 243 map1.png)...disabled (restricted).

moodle.sty: Converting 'map1.png' to base64...
runsystem(openssl enc -base64 -in map1.png -out map1.enc)...disabled (restricte
d).
```

tells you that the shell escape is not enabled.

If you look at the start of your log file, you should see

```
[romano:~/education … icosGIT/E-F2_19-20] master 7m22s ± pdflatex --shell-escape=true
pdflatex: option '--shell-escape' doesn't allow an argument
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**x
```

So I suppose the problem is that the option is `--shell-escape`, **not** `--shell-escape=true`.

Then you have to check if you have ImageMagick (for `convert`) and openssl (for the base64 conversion) installed.

And finally, you should use the full name of your graphic file, including the extension. There are patches floating around to correct this, but they are quite tricky...

Comment: hm, the log snippets above say texlive/2018 not miktex ;-).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer erm... so the OP is confused on the distribution they have... will tell it in the answer.

Comment: Hi Rmano, so I don't get that warning anymore, but even with new installations of OpenSSL from here (https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html), ImageMagick from here (https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows), and GhostScript from here (https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) (for good measure as ImageMagick highly recommended it), I'm still getting a blank where the base64 output should be.

Comment: Right!  Thank you Ulrike.  I got myself mixed up as the "Dvi Viewer" in the Texmaker Configuration had "C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/yap.exe" %.dvi

Whoops.

Comment: @fcturner is something failed it should be in the log. Otherwise, you can try my little hack in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/548400/moodlle-package-problem-with-includegraphics-dan-tikzpicture to show the command issued by `moodle.sty` and try to debug them.

Comment: Thanks @Rmano, here's the new log:

moodle.sty: Processing \includegraphics[width=6cm]{map1} for HTML...
moodle.sty: Converting 'map1' to PNG...
command is: convert map1 -resize 243 map1.png
runsystem(convert map1 -resize 243 map1.png)...executed.

command is: openssl enc -base64 -in map1.png -out map1.enc
runsystem(openssl enc -base64 -in map1.png -out map1.enc)...executed.

command is: openssl enc -base64 -in map1.png -out map1.enc
moodle.sty: Reading base64 file 'map1.enc'...
moodle.sty: <IMG> tag inserted.

It doesn't say anything has failed, and yet it's not in the .xml file

Comment: Hmm... yes, it seems ok. I really don't know. Check if all the intermediate files are ok, the png and the `.enc` (which is a quite big blob, normally). Try to go manually step by step through the conversion command to see if something is failing in a subtle way.

Comment: Ah! Try `\includegraphics[width=6cm]{map1.pdf}` with the extension...

Comment: Or `{map1.png}`, whatever the file type. `convert` wants full names, so `convert map1 -resize 243 map1.png` will not work unless you have a graphical `map1` file without extension. In my experience is better starting with `pdf` files.

Comment: Just tried both .png and .pdf after getting gnuplot to generate the plots as .pdf, with no luck.

Not sure where to find the intermediate files, but I'll try that out and see where I can get.  Thanks @Rmano!

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but I had the problem solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453

Comment: So converting with ImageMagick seems fine through the cmd prompt, and when I run an OpenSSL cmd prompt I can encrypt it as base64 without issue (see new image in my original post).  When I copy the text manually to put it into the .xml file, Moodle imports it perfectly!  Not sure which other steps I can check.  One thing is, the .enc files don't show up in the same directory as the original .tex file (actually, I still haven't found them, whereas doing it manually I found it on the desktop as I'd wished).  Any thoughts on where to go next?

Comment: No, but the files `.enc` *must* appear in the same directory as the `.tex` file. That's probably the reason for the problem.

Comment: So it looks like the openssl encryption isn't happening at all - I get a transient message as pdfLaTeX is running saying it doesn't recognize it (see edit at the bottom of the post).  Tried running tekmaker as an administrator with no noticeable difference.

Comment: Okay, so including @UlrikeFischer 's change of command AND using an OpenSSL cmd window to run `pdflatex -shell-escape circles.tex` made it run just fine.  It must be something with how I have TeXMaker configured.  Thanks to both of you!